# Voting Functionality Ruby on Rails - Easy Question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, blogs, voting

I want to add a "like" functionality to a blog I am creating in Ruby on Rails to let people "thumbs up" a post. Then I would like to be able to display the most liked posts in the side bar. I am new to rails so rely heavily on tutorials and stack overflow. Any good resources or what is this even called. I assumed "voting" for this question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should look up link_to_remote and using AJAX with rails. Here is a nice tutorial to get started: http://railsonedge.blogspot.com/2008/03/tutorial-beginning-ajax-with-rails-20.html

The idea would be:

- The user clicks on "vote"
- It sends an asynchronous message to the controller to save the vote. (use `link_to_remote`)
- the :complete callback does something (eg "thanks for voting!")
- the :update changes the voting zone (eg "voted. 6 votes on this")

There are a lot of [tutorials](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-and-ajax.htm) on the subject.

---

EDIT: I wrote that a while ago and since then the best practices have changed. Now please take a look at how to do that using unobstrusive javascript. Good resources include Ryan [Bates Bates's railscast #205](http://railscasts.com/episodes/205-unobtrusive-javascript) and the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) to understand the principle.

> "Unobtrusive JavaScript" is an
>   emerging technique in the JavaScript
>   programming language, as used on the
>   World Wide Web. Though the term is not
>   formally defined, its basic principles
>   are generally understood to include:
>
> - Separation of functionality (the
>     "behavior layer") from a Web page's
>     structure/content and presentation
> - Best practices to avoid the problems
>     of traditional JavaScript programming
>     (such as browser inconsistencies and
>     lack of scalability)
> - Progressive enhancement to support
>     user agents that may not support
>     advanced JavaScript functionality[

Comment: Awesome man thanks. Just didn't know where to look. This helps a lot.

Comment: You're welcome. It's pretty hard to find documentation when begining. Consider reading a book about rails if you want to really grasp everything about it. I've listed some on an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386469/best-ruby-and-ruby-on-rails-books

Answer (score 2):

I know this is not exactly what you are looking for, but there is a very good ["star-rating" plugin](http://github.com/edgarjs/ajaxful-rating) that you could look at for some ideas of what to do. It uses ajax and all that goodie-goodieness ;)

Answer (score 2):

The book Simply Rails 2 has something similar to this (a vote up, vote down sort of thing) and you might want to pick it up just because it is a good book to get you started on things.

Simply Rails 2.

Answer (score 2):

[gem thumbs_up](https://github.com/brady8/thumbs_up)  for rails 3 or [gem vote_fu](https://github.com/peteonrails/vote_fu) for rails 2.* applications can help you...